# GitLab: How to filter bad formats?

Tags: linux, git, gitlab

I want to make sure users wont be able to push some formats. I would like to check the file format before uploading the file to the GitLab server. the Web Hooks affects only the specific project, while I want the whole server be filtered. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found out what to do. I used Hooks. you can add your own script inside this path:

> /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks/

you can edit the existing samples. I wrote in Ruby and another script in Bash, just make sure you add "#!/bin/bash" (or whatever script language you write) to the file header. make sure you bring the file CHMOD 755 or higher, and the file name should be the [event name](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) (without any format, just "pre-rereceive" for example).

notice that you get some parameters, you can read in "pre-receive.sample" notes. Good luck.